# How different does expect behave on ARM and X86?

Tags: bash, arm, expect

i am working on some bash scripts that can cooperate with automatically, e.g. i need to ssh log on some device and run scripts and be informed when script exits. And the devices can be very different, but i want to use uniform scripts in order to run a bunch of test cases automatically. Besides compiling expect on ARM, is there other risk? do i have to write different expect scripts for different systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The architecture doesn't matter, but the operating system and environment does.

If you run Debian on ARM and Debian on x86, you will likely not see a difference at all, and both expect and the bash scripts will work exactly the same.

However, if you run NetBSD and Debian on two x86 machines, the scripts may behave completely differently if great care is not taken to only use portable features.

Portability matters even if both the x86 and the ARM systems run Linux, since you may find that the x86 distro uses full GNU tools while the ARM system uses smaller and less feature rich busybox.

If you write your scripts in such a way that they don't rely on anything available on one platform but not the other, running them with expect over ssh will work just fine.